# Trying to change svg fill with Huebee.buzz without success

Tags: svg, fill

I'm not a professional!
I try to work with huebee.buzz and manipulate the fill of an svg. But it seems that I don't get it at all.

Please look into this jsFiddle (link below) then you surely understand what I'm trying to do: Selecting a color in the Choice-Div should change the fill of the red svg with black stroke.
What do I miss here? It doesn't look like there is a connection between my svg and the huebee.buzz-thing.

Is there anyone out there who could explain it to me, I don't find much information through google searches.

Thanks in advance!

`<https://jsfiddle.net/marbaslam/thdyp9c3/138/>`

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear, I can answer my question by myself *roll eyes*

I did this:

```
var dingsbums = document.getElementById("path46");
hueb.on('change', function(color) {
dingsbums.style.fill = color;
});
```

... and it worked as intended.